# conda --list [Illegal instruction] on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, anaconda, debian

My Raspberry Pi OS is raspios-bullseye-arm64.I successfully installed Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-aarch64 on Raspberry Pi.I can successfully use the "conda" command.But,When I use "conda listh" or other commands such as "conda activate" I will get an error "Illegal instruction".I want to use conda on Raspberry Pi 64 os.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Raspeberry is still using 32bit version of programs, so you should not use aarch64

Comment: same situation. $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v8+ #1488 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 18 16:16:16 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: [more} same situation. $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v8+ #1488 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 18 16:16:16 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux Tried to find conda with apt, (with default repositories) no luck. Tried https:/docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/rpm-debian.html then apt search finds conda/stable 4.9.2-0 amd64 but apt install reports E: Unable to locate package conda. https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-aarch64.sh fails to install fully. Adding miniconda3/bin to $PATH doesn't work. Troubling.

Comment: Could you please go over your question again? Some of the commands are typos, so it is important to know if the typo came when inputting the question or literally what was entered into the shell. E.g., `conda --list` isn't a valid command, neither is `conda listh`

Comment: I successfully installed Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh.Miniconda can be used normally in Pi 64 OS.

Comment: "*I successfully installed...*" - please post that as an Answer, not a comment. Self-answering is very much welcome here!

Comment: Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh (March) did install. However the current (both Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh and Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-aarch64.sh) did not install correctly. After installing 4.9.2 and issuing conda upgrade conda seemed to upgrade but after it finished it didn't work. Is 4.9.2 reasonably current and reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution - don't install latest version. Drop back to Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh (March 2021). Once installed do not update conda. As of this posting Miniconda3-py39_4.10.3-Linux-aarch64.sh (July 2021) doesn't work.

Comment: Got more current by installing minforge vs. miniconda. As of today conda -V reports 4.11.0. Conda list includes python 3.9.9, scikit-learn 1.0.2, and spyder 5.2.1. Install minifordge first. Then create an environment with python=3.9 (don't let it install python 4.x or Spyder won't install.) Install Spyder using conda to your new environment.  Got rid of miniconda3 directory and edited .bashrc to use the minifordge directory vs. miniconda3.